# Typical scoring parameter choices for cross-validation of ranking classifier rank:pairwise

Tags: cross-validation, xgboost, ranking, predict, multilabel-classification

I am building XGBoost ranking classifier using Python `xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier` ([XGBClassifier](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html)). In my problem, I try to classify ranking labels that vary in `0,1,2,3`. In the classifier setup, I used `objective = "rank:pairwise"`. I now want to run cross-validation with `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score` ([cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)).

**Are there any canonical choices of `scoring` function to assess the rank outcome classification performance?**

I am thinking `scoring = "neg_mean_squared_error"` seems like an OK choice as it weights the distance between the two labels, i.e. accounts for the ranking character of the outcome.

I hope to get other comments/opinions/experiences on that.